# Sources for some old BASIC games

Tags: basic

Poking about in early issues of **Dr Dobbs' Journal** (the journal of the *People's Computer Company*, or PCC) I came across a listing for [BASIC games available on tape](https://archive.org/details/dr_dobbs_journal_vol_01/page/n64). Many of these are widespread, but a number I have not heard of and Google is not helping. Does anyone have listings for:

- Motie
- Rescue
- Trader (assume early version of space trader?)
- Crash

Comment: a note for future explorers: Bob Albrecht of PCC's domain `dragonfun.net` has gone through a *lot* of owners and most of them are quite NSFW. If it's a newer archive than 2001 or so, click with care ...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Here](https://archive.computerhistory.org/resources/access/text/2017/09/102661095/102661095-05-v4-n4-acc.pdf#page=20) is the listing for Motie, followed immediately by Rescue. The full list of archived issues of People's Computer Co. (PCC) is [here](https://www.computerhistory.org/collections/catalog/102661095).

Comment: Unfortunately, the OCR provided by that didn't work very well: `31'" III" C'fISI 'SAV[ "001'1 FO" IS TU"NS .... GOT) IHU 'CONTINU[`

Comment: Most excellent! I'll use that to track down the original.

Comment: @StopHarmingMonica If you want an authentic 70s BASIC gamer experience, then there is only one way to get printed code into your computer: Type it off by hand :)

Comment: @Philipp even better: not realise you can edit previous lines, so every time you make a mistake start over from scratch

Answer (score 1):

I have a book of printed BASIC computer games I got on eBay by David H. Ahl.  I bought this for nostalgic purposes and for actually running on my homemade Z80 computer running BASIC.  I had this book as a kid and it was my introduction to programming, a lifelong pursuit and career...

I think Ahl published two books, a yellow one and a red one.  Look on Amazon or eBay for used volumes.

Comment: 99% certain I had the same book (the yellow one).

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across another good source.  When I had my Radio Shack TRS-80 Model I and was in college, I used to subscribe to SoftSide Magazine which published games for Radio Shack, Atari, and Apple computers.  [This link](https://archive.org/details/softside-magazine-31) goes directly to an issue I was searching for because I played the game on the cover so much that I ported it to my Commodore 64, and later to the IBM PC.

Answer (score 0):

The page has a hint that the games are listed in [What to Do After you Hit Return](https://archive.org/details/Whattodoafteryouhitreturn/).

- Trader is [Star Trader](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trader), as listed starting on page [143](https://archive.org/details/Whattodoafteryouhitreturn/page/n141/mode/2up?q=Star+Trader)
- Crash is a modified version of *Lunar Lander*, listed on page [151](https://archive.org/details/Whattodoafteryouhitreturn/page/n149/mode/2up?q=Star+Trader).

While typing in the code would be a chore, maybe searching for comment strings will turn up the full source.